# Powershell separate curly braces

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

```
ColumnA|ColumnB|Column|CColumnD
blah   blah   blah   @{automaticmanagementenabled=true, blah=1}
```

I want to list all the rows whose `automaticManagementEnabled=true` and export them to csv. The data is inside curly braces like

```
$data = import-csv |
where {$_.secretMAnagement -eq @{automaticManagementenabled=true}}
```

Comment: Show us your code and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `@{ame=true,abc=1,blahblah=0}` is PowerShell's way of showing an **object**. If you use `Export-Csv -Path 'theResult.csv' -NoTypeInformation` on the resuls of your code, you _should_ get a proper CSV file. However, since you didn't show us any code, we can't tell how you get your output...

Comment: $data= import.csv c:\file.csv | where {$_.secretManagement -eq @{automaticManagementEnabled=true}                                                                               secretManagement is the header in the csv file

Comment: Please update the post, and avoid posting it in the comments.

Comment: You forgot to add your code.

Comment: So the curly braces notation is already in the csv you are importing? Why not create that csv as it should be and be done with it? Also please show us the desired result. Should all columns be present there? Please try to [Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the code and examples in your question. From what I can see in your code, I guess you want `Where-Object {$_.secretMAnagement -match 'automaticManagementenabled=true'}`

Comment: @Theo -match did the work. Thanks